# Share a list between different processes?

Tags: python, list, multiprocessing

I have the following problem. I have written a function that takes a list as input and creates a dictionary for each element in the list. I then want to append this dictionary to a new list, so I get a list of dictionaries. I am trying to spawn multiple processes for this. My problem here is that I want the different processes to access the list of dictionaries as it is updated by other processes, for example to print something once the has reached a certain length.

My example would be like this:

```
import multiprocessing

list=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']

def do_stuff(element):
    element_dict={}
    element_dict['name']=element
    new_list=[]
    new_list.append(element_dict)
    if len(new_list)>3:
        print 'list > 3'

###Main###
pool=multiprocessing.Pool(processes=6)
pool.map(do_stuff, list)
pool.close()
```

Right now my problem is that each process creates its own `new_list`. Is there a way to share the list between processes, such that all dictionaries are appended to the same list? Or is the only way to define the `new_list` outside of the function?

Comment: Use a [Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues).

Comment: Or an [Array](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

One way is to use a manager object and create your shared list object from it:

```
from multiprocessing import Manager, Pool

input_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']

manager = Manager()
shared_list = manager.list()

def do_stuff(element):
    element_dict = {}
    element_dict['name'] = element
    shared_list.append(element_dict)
    if len(shared_list) > 3:
        print('list > 3')

pool = Pool(processes=6)
pool.map(do_stuff, input_list)
pool.close()
```

Remember, unlike threads, processes do not share memory space. (When spawned, each process gets its own copy of the memory footprint of the spawning process, and then runs with it.) So they can only communicate via some form of IPC (interprocess communication). In Python, one such method is `multiprocessing.Manager` and the data structures it exposes, e.g. `list` or `dict`. These are used in code as easily as their built-in equivalents, but under the hood utilize some form of IPC (sockets probably).

**Edit Feb 1, 2022:** Removed unneeded
`global shared_list` declaration from the function, since the object is not being replaced.

Comment: Thank you! I tried to put in a manager object already, but did not really get it to work...

Comment: This doesn't work on windows because there each process gets its own `shared_list` so that the list isn't shared.  Also this is some kind of „fork bomb“ because each process creates its own `Pool` and starts 6 other processes which also create their own `Pool` objects and start 6 other processes which also…

Comment: `global` is a bad idea anyway but here it really is wrong. `shared_list` and `pool` need to be local in a function, that function has to be guarded to be called just in the main program and not at import of the module, and the list must be given as argument to `do_stuff()`.

Comment: @BlackJack, ```global``` is not always a bad idea--it is part of the language for a reason, after all--but in this case was unnecessary, so I removed it. Thx for bringing to my attention. And the idea here is to solve the problem and illustrate an issue with minimal changes to OP's code, not to design a bulletproof reusable module. Putting everything in "module" namespace makes the point clear.

Comment: @VelimirMlaker Look up how this (doesn't) work on Windows in the Python documentation.  It doesn't have to be bullet proof, but I would think answers should address obvious severe problems and pitfalls.

Answer (score 1):

the following is from [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html):

```
from multiprocessing import shared_memory
a = shared_memory.ShareableList(['howdy', b'HoWdY', -273.154, 100, None, True, 42])
[ type(entry) for entry in a ]
[<class 'str'>, <class 'bytes'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'NoneType'>, <class 'bool'>, <class 'int'>]
a[2]
-273.154
a[2] = -78.5
a[2]
-78.5
a[2] = 'dry ice'  # Changing data types is supported as well
a[2]
'dry ice'
a[2] = 'larger than previously allocated storage space'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
ValueError: exceeds available storage for existing str
a[2]
'dry ice'
len(a)
7
a.index(42)
6
a.count(b'howdy')
0
a.count(b'HoWdY')
1
a.shm.close()
a.shm.unlink()
del a  # Use of a ShareableList after call to unlink() is unsupported
```

Comment: please consider using the space provided to elaborate on why your answer works.

Answer (score 0):

can run in win10

```
import multiprocessing

list=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']

def do_stuff(element,sharedlist):
    element_dict={}
    element_dict['name']=element
    sharedlist.append(element_dict)
    print(sharedlist)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool=multiprocessing.Pool(processes=6)
    manager=multiprocessing.Manager()
    sharedlist=manager.list()
    tasks = [(x,sharedlist) for x in list]
    pool.starmap(do_stuff, tasks)
    pool.close()
```