# How to access global variable in Pool.map in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a global variable where It keeps track of 2d matrix coordinates of a elements in a variable row and column
In the main function. I called it by

```
global row
global column
...
...
row.append()
column.append()
```

So that appending to the list will be changed in global scope allowing me to access it in different functions.
However, I ran into a peculiar problem with it while using Pool.
Also in my main method I have,

```
Pool.map(otherfucntion, iterablethingy)
```

when it jumps to `otherfunction` , because `row` and `column` was declared globally, I should be able to use those two variables in `otherfunction` when its called through map. However, `row` and `column` gets "cleared(?)"

I ran the debugger and right before the line

```
Pool.map(otherfunction, iterablethingy)
```

my `row` has row = [1,1,1,1,1,1]
my `column` has column[1,2,3,4,5,6]
BUT, when it gets to

```
Pool.map(otherfucntion, iterablethingy)
```

`row` and `column` is cleared...
giving me `row = []` `column = []` which gives me undesirable function call results.
For some reason, with out Pool, I do get my desirable result even through `map()`

I need to be able to use `row` and `column` inside the `otherfunction` through Pool.map

I've tried to pass `row` and `column` as parameters by

```
Pool.map(otherfunction, iterablethingy, row, column)
...
...
def otherfunction(iterablethingy, row, column)
```

But then I get

```
TypeError: map() takes from 3 to 4 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

I understand there are similar version of this kind of question on stackoverflow, but none of them seems to help me solve out my particular problem...

Minimal reproductive code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import copy


cell1 = []
row = list()
column = list()

def main():
    global cell1

    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    cell1 = [['.', 'O', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
             ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
             ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
             ['O', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
             ['.', '.', 'O', '.', 'O', '.'],
             ['.', '.', '.', '.', 'O', '.']]

    for x, ele1 in enumerate(cell1):
        for y, ele2 in enumerate(ele1):
            global row
            global column
            row.append(x)
            column.append(y)

    cell2 = [copy.deepcopy(cell1)]
    cell1 = pool.map(myfunc, cell2)
    print(cell1)

def myfunc(cell2):
    for x in range(0,len(row)):
        if(cell2[row[x]][column[x]]) == '.':
            cell1[row[x]][column[x]] = 'X'
    return cell1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Please help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Share a list between different processes in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40630428/share-a-list-between-different-processes-in-python)

Comment: no because I'm not changing my list that is global, I'm just trying to access it

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] of this issue?

Comment: If it's a read-only value, the simplest thing to do is pass it as an argument to the `otherfucntion`. Each process runs in its own memory-space, so you can't share values via global variables as you can in a regular Python script.

Comment: I think you should look again into the `Manager` object. It provides all you need. Or use `starmap` instead of map and provide suitable tuples containing `row` and `column` to it.

Comment: why does the values inside row and column disappear when pool.map is called?