# How do i share a list in python using multiprocessing

Tags: python, list, multiprocessing, share

I'm trying to have shared access to a list, every time i press the **hotkey 'q'**, i would like to append and get the same result as process **a** ['something'] every time i press, but instead the output of the process **b** is [] instead of ['something'], etc.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from pynput import keyboard
from time import sleep

list1 = list()


def on_press(key):
    if str(key).replace("'", '') == 'q':
        list1.append('something')
        print(f'process a: {list1}')


def keysinput():
    global listener
    while True:
        with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
            listener.join()


def printsharedlist():
    while True:
        print(f'process b: {list1}')
        sleep(3)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = Process(target=keysinput)
    a.start()
    b = Process(target=printsharedlist)
    b.start()
```

**Output after pressing 'q'**

```
process a: []
process b: ['something']
```

**Expected after pressing 'q'**

```
process a: ['something']
process b: ['something']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Share a list between different processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40630428/share-a-list-between-different-processes)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way:

```
from multiprocessing import Manager, Process
from pynput import keyboard
from time import sleep


def on_press(key):
    global listreturn
    if str(key).replace("'", '') == 'q':
        print(key)
        listreturn = 'something'
        return listener.stop()


def keysinput(list2):
    global listener
    while True:
        print(f'process a: {list2}')
        with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
            listener.join()
        list2.append(listreturn)


def printsharedlist(list2):
    while True:
        print(f'process b: {list2}')
        sleep(3)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()
    list1 = manager.list()
    a = Process(target=keysinput, args=(list1,))
    b = Process(target=printsharedlist, args=(list1,))
    a.start()
    b.start()
    a.join()
    b.join()
```